# JSF & Hashmap: access value properties

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a Hashmap defined by:

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<String, Person>();
```

and it's filled by some data. This is in EJB bean.

In JSF, I would like to access property of class Person somehow like:

```
#{bean.map['key'].username}
```

but JSF doesn't allow me to do this.

If I replace Person with String for example, it works.

Any help?

Comment: Does `Person` have a `getUsername()` getter?

Comment: how bout overriding toString() for the `Person ` ?

Comment: does it work with an alternative notation, like  `#{bean.map.key.username}` - btw which version of JSF?

Comment: Yes, it has getter.

Overriding don't solve my problem, because Person is complex object and has more than one field, and I need to access other too.

JSF version is 2.0.

Comment: what exactly is the error message? are you using it in a table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19091496/4712391

Answer (score -1):

A solution might be writing your own custom EL function:

```
public static Object getMapValue(Map map, Object key) {
    return map.get(key);
}
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
#{fn:getMapValue(bean.map, 'key').username}
```

If you are not familiar with custom el functions, check this: [Facelets EL Functions can save your day](http://faces.eti.br/2008/11/02/facelets-el-functions-can-save-your-day/)

Answer (score -1):

Write a function in the Bean

```
public Person getMapValue(String key)
{
        return map.get(key);
}
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
#{bean.getMapValue('key').username}
```