# How to input values to HashMap in bean using Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page where I have to associate two fields using key-value pair and save. For example, I have a number of `participant`s who has `price`s. If I use two `p:inputText` fields to enter their values, how should the backing bean look like?

Also, I want to display the number of such pairs of `p:inputText` fields according to the number of participants I enter. I have a similar question answered here [How to insert a primefaces input text dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064274/how-to-insert-a-primefaces-input-text-dynamically/19066442?noredirect=1#19066442). But I want to be able to submit the values to a key-value pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In EL, you can treat maps exactly the same way as entity/model beans.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.map.key1}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.map.key2}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.map.key3}" />
```

This example will put the input values under map keys `key1`, `key2` and `key3`.

Note: make sure that the map isn't `null`. Like as with normal entity/model beans, JSF/EL won't precreate it for you. Do it in the `@PostConstruct` yourself.

Comment: @BaluC would you suggest good book of Expression language , how it works and what capabilities it has in terms of Computation , is it Turing complete etc?) Thanks